# Is it a good practice to use method names that flow properly when spoken?

Tags: naming, functions

For example, suppose if I had a `Character` class and an inventory, before taking out a weapon to use it, it's probably a good idea to check if that weapon exists first, so I might have a method called `has(GameObject weapon);` that returns a boolean. I can then use it in an `if` statement like this:

```
if character.has(sword):
    # rest of code here
```

I like this because it almost sounds like English and flows better. However, I could also have a method called `check_inventory(GameObject weapon);` that does the same thing, but doesn't flow as well, for example:

```
if character.check_inventory(GameObject Weapon)
    # rest of code
```

Which approach is better? In the second example, does it break encapsulation to suggest we are checking a collection of some type?

Comment: `has()` is pretty broad.  Can you compromise and use something like `hasInventoryItem()`?

Comment: "has" does flow better.  But, it **might** be ambiguous.  For example, what if you are checking if a Character had a particular Spell or Feat (I play some D&D, your terminology might differ).  How would you check that?  So you might want to be a but more specific, like `hasItem()`, `hasAbility()`, etc...

Comment: Once upon a time there was this language in which people were supposed to code by writing english sentences that everybody could understand.... cobol, isn’t it ? was it really so much more practical?

Comment: @DanPichelman - No compromise necessary, it's was a thought I had while reading an article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While its nice to be able to make the code write sentences, outside of limited situations it becomes impractical.

For a start English is too vague to separate clearly things like `character.Has(sword)` and `character.Has(measles)` with single words.

Secondly `if(character.Has(sword))` reads nicely but, say we want to check the character the monster is attacking or something.

```
monster.IsAttacking.Has(sword)
```

Makes less sense. Its simply clearer to use longer terms that always make sense, but dont read as sentences eg.

```
monster.AttackTarget.Inventory.Any(i=> i is Sword)
```

You do see this form in things like test frameworks, mocks or Linq, for example.

Comment: In a strongly typed language, `character.Has(sword) and character.Has(measles)` could work fine.  But may be pushing it.

Comment: good point, although of course the method name may lose meaning if you overload it for different purposes

Comment: Although I would argument that "IsAttacking" should be renamed "Victim" or "VictimBeingAttacked" or "TargetOfAttack": `if monster.TargetOfAttack.Has(sword)` reads pretty nicely as a sentence. Even `monster.TargetOfAttack` is pretty self explanatory too. Naming things is hard.

Comment: @user949300: You are correct. A strongly typed language with multiple overloads of "Has" accepting different arguments would work. I've found most people: 1) Ignore method overloads unless you explicitly tell them to look; 2) Don't look at the names of the Types for arguments of overloads (even though I tell them to look at those names); 3) Do not ever look at the names of arguments to methods; and 4) Do not think the names of variables have anything to do with the method names that follow after the `.` character. Not that I'm frustrated by this or anything...

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that unit testing libraries try hard to make code read nicely. I assume this is to help non programmers understand and maybe write tests. For regular code I have not seen much of this and it doesn't seem terribly helpful.

I have a feeling that programmers don't actually read code left to right like a book but instead skip around a lot. So the fact that code reads like a sentence may not actually be very helpful.

One thing that is very important is using names that can be spoken properly. For example a variable called 'passwd' is harder to say than 'password' which makes communication with others harder when you can't properly say the name.

Answer (score 1):

`has` is better than `check_inventory`. In most languages it is the convention that methods (and properties) which return a boolean should be phrased as a yes/no question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can go further and apply "Tell, don't ask" approach.

```
character.AttackWith(sword)
```

Then if character hasn't sword, attack will have no affect - do nothing or something else based on your logic.

Comment: I'd actually suggest `weapon = character.bestWeaponVs(monster); character.attackMonsterWith(monster, weapon);`

Comment: Doesn't this just push the problem to a different place? For the check will be inside of `AttackWith` now.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I would say remove problem from the consumer of `character`. Now the class who is actually responsible for knowing it's inventory can make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to design your program for readability, but keep your audience in mind.

Your audience is programmers. Of course, they'll appreciate a fluent interface like `character.has(sword)`, but more important is that they'll understand the semantics of your code. And the wording `has()` can too easily be interpreted in many different ways.